# Proof of limit in analysis

Tags: analysis, limits, exponential-function, factorial

I've read the following question in a book :

''Prove that limit as $n$ goes to infinity of  $n/(n!)^{1/n}$ = $e$.''

I've tried to prove it using the definition of a limit, but it's really complicated.

Comment: Also, it's false. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n!}}=0$.

Comment: @ClementC. that's not the same formula as OP had

Comment: one strategy is to prove that as n goes to infinity, your sequence is always less than e.  Then prove it's always greater than e.

Comment: @ClementC. typing mistake..

Comment: @MohammadAthar that was.

Comment: @Lola If you are allowed to use it... Stirling's approximation would solve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments thus far have hinted, this is a nontrivial problem to do from first principles, but turns out to be essentially equivalent to a well-known result called [Stirling's formula or Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#Derivation). Note that since $\log x$ is continuous at $x=e$, it is equivalent to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg( \log\frac n{(n!)^{1/n}} \bigg) = \log e \qquad\text{or}\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} \big( \tfrac1n\log(n!) - \log n \big) = -1.
$$
There are several ways to derive this limit, including some given at the link above.